# how to set backspace button in place ActionbarDrawerToggle to navigate to previous fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am calling fragments from Main_activity.java and also calling fragments from other fragments but i want to show backspace(<-) arrow button when any fragment is loaded(either from Main_activity or any other fragments) instead of ActionBarDrawerToggle. how can I achieve this?
Main Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NavigationView nav;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
ImageView homeInToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    nav=findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
    drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer);
   // homeInToolbar=findViewById(R.id.homeInToolbar);

    toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    nav.setCheckedItem(R.id.menu_home);


    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout,new HomeFragment()).commit();}
```

[Main_Activity where the toogle is shown and after click on students, the image should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih2yr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 lines after setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
In main_activity from where I calling the fragment, I have disabled toggle as shown in below code.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout,new FeeFragment(toggle)).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

and where ever necessary, I can enable toggle by below code.

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```